# Picking a voltage regulator for 12V/10A input -> 3V/290mA output

Tags: voltage-regulator

Am I doing the correctly?

[ATSAMD21G17A-AU](http://datasheet.octopart.com/ATSAMD21G17A-AU-Atmel-datasheet-24968745.pdf) p.906 - ARM-Based Microcontroller - 7mA

[MAX-7Q-0](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/MAX-7_DataSheet_(UBX-13004068).pdf) p.16 - GNSS module (GPS) - 67mA

[LPS25H](https://upverter.com/datasheet/b22b95d54fd7019da37a3f4ab507b579b8668488.pdf) P.8 - Barometer - 25uA

[Si7013-A20-IM1](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si7013-A20.pdf) p.4 - Temperature - 180uA

[AT24MAC602-STUM-T](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-8807-seeprom-at24mac402-602-datasheet.pdf) p.6 - EEPROM - 3mA

[XB24-Z7WIT-004](https://upverter.com/datasheet/d4a37a158a10c255acd3b6791c281d403628cd4b.pdf) p.2 - ZigBee - 220mA

So total about 290mA current draw. The circuit is running at 3.3V. I'd like it to handle up to 12V/10A input.

Would something like the [MIC5219-3.3YM5-TR](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/mic5219-779135.pdf) be OK? I did [this](http://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Power-Management-ICs/LDO-Voltage-Regulators/_/N-5cgac?P=1z0wd8oZ1z0shyuZ1z0wa2eZ1yzvdtp) search on Mouser. Is there a better choice?

Comment: Just use the 7803 or 7833.

Comment: TPS62175 would be my personal preference.

Comment: If it's a linear regulator, the input current will be about the same (within a mA) of the output current. If it's a buck regulator, the input current will be about 1/4 of the output current. It makes no sense to ask for 10 A input at 12 V if you only need 0.3 A output at 3 V.

Answer (score 1):

No, that  MIC5219-3.3YM5-TR will not cut it, you need something beefier than that.

But first: this is how adapters work, a 12V/10A adapter supplies 12 V **with a current between 0 (zero) and 10 A**.

The adapter does not **supply** the 10 A, it **can** supply upto 10A. How much current flows depends on the **load**, so not the adapter. As long as the load does not require more than 10 A, this will work with the 12V/10A adapter.

A regulator (like the  MIC5219-3.3YM5-TR) is simply a device that takes an input voltage, 12 V for example, and converts it to a lower value, like 3V. The 9 V difference between input (12 V) and output (3 V) has to "go somewhere". The simplest is to converted to heat but more heat is generated as the current gets higher, uint128_t's answer shows that in your case (0.3 A) quite some heat is generated. So the regulator will need cooling in the form of a heatsink. You need to do some calculations to determine what heatsink you need.

But the MIC5219-3.3YM5-TR cannot even handle the amount of power (resulting in heat) that it would need to dissipate for your 300 mA so we need to look elsewhere. There are other linear regulators that could do the job like the old LM317 but this is old hat and inefficient and still requires a large heatsink.

Fortunately there's a simpler and cheaper solution that does not require a  heatsink. This uses a **switching regulator**. I recommend an L2596 based module which you can buy on for example [on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2596-Step-Down-Module-Buck-Converter-1-23V-30V-Output-DC-DC-Power-Supply-/251066005460). They're cheap, you feed it with the 12 V from your adapter, then measure the output voltage and use the potmeter on the module to set the voltage to 3 V. Yes it is really that simple. I often use these modules and they just work.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheet is very nice, and has all the thermal calcs wrapped up in a nice little equation. First (assuming 350 mA draw to give yourself some margin), Pd = (Vin - Vout) * Iout + Vin * Ignd = (12V - 3.3V) * 350 mA + 12 V * ~1 mA = **3.06 W**.

Then, check against the Pd(max) given a minimum footprint layout. Pd(max) = (Tj(max) - Tamb)/ThetaJA = (125ºC - 25ºC)/(220ºC/W) = **455 mW** << 3.06W.

Conclusion: **no**, this will not work.

Or, to put it another way, you can calculate the junction temperature with Pd = 3.06 W and Tamb = 25ºC:

Tj = Tamb + Pd * ThetaJA = 25ºC + 3.06 W/(220ºC/W) = 698ºC

Mathematica helpfully informs me that this is "37.9ºC above the melting point of aluminium", and I admit that seems a little extreme, but the math seems correct.

In short, pick a different linear regulator, use a lower voltage supply, or use a switcher.

Also, just a note: specifying input current makes no sense. So "12V/10A in" is nonsensical, the regulator and downstream components will draw only the current they require.

Comment: Well I have an old laptop power supply thats 12V/10A... I was hoping to have it work. But I'd like a 9V power supply or a 5V supply work as well. Maybe I just don't understand how regulators work.

Comment: I think you don't understand how _current_ works. See Fake's answer. The power supply doesn't push 10 A through whatever's connected but _can_ supply up to 10 A if the load demands it. Otherwise it just supplies the current required by the load and this appears low in your case.